# Android - How to send data to onDestroy method of a service

Tags: android

I have a service which is run by a button in an activity. This service register a broadcast receiver. I kknow the way to get data from the activity when the onStartCommand method starts (bundle bundle = intent.getExtras());

My question : how can I do if want to get data from the activity when the onDestroy method starts ? In other words : I want to take care of what checkboxes an user checked when the onDestroy method is called because the actions depends from the checkboxes.

Any ideas ?

Thanks

Comment: Something sounds weird. Why does the service care what checkboxes are checked? How does a service have checkboxes? Shouldn't that information be sent in the intent? WHen you say "actions" do you mean what the service does?

Comment: The service can register (with a button) 3 BroadcastReceivers (it depends on the 3 checkboxes in the activit). I also have a "stop" button in this activity. When I click on the right checkboxes and I click on this button, I stop the service and then I am in the onDestroy method. I want this method, in the service class, to know what checkboxes, in my activity, are checked. Is that clearer ? As you said, I use Intent to send data to the onStartCommand method. The stopservice method does not include an intent in its declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling stopService you can call startService and pass in a boolean "shutdown" to be equal to true and other information you want to pass, in the onStartCommand you can check for the "shutdown" flag and process the other pass in information and then call stopSelf(). Sample code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
intent.putExtra("shutdown", true);
intent.putExtra(otherdata);
startService(intent);
```

in MyService  onStartCommand

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
{
        if (intent != null)
        {
            // get the data and process
            if (intent.getBooleanExtra("shutdown", false);
            {
                stopSelf();
            }
          }
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save data in your sharedperference and check it in your ondestory of service.